# Need explanation about PHP syntax

Tags: php, yii, syntax

found cosole command in Yii. And there I found method:

```
 public function getHelp()
 {
    $output = "This command will allow you to remove some Yii temporary data \n\n";

    return $output.parent::getHelp();
 }
```

I cant understand what does mean this:

```
 return $output.parent::getHelp();
```

I know this

```
parent::getHelp();
```

call parent method. But what do full construction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.` is the string-concatenation operator in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). So, the code you are looking at just returns the value of `$output` concatenated with the value of `parent::getHelp();`. If `$output` is `foo` and `parent:getHelp()` returns `bar`, then the `return` value is `foobar`.